# Transpose row to column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
oGroup     oDate          oValue
--------------------------------
A          2014-01-01     20
A          2014-01-02     30
B          2014-01-01     5
B          2014-01-02     15
C          2014-01-01     40
C          2014-01-02     60
```

I want to have the following result:

```
oGroup   2014-01-01     2014-01-02
----------------------------------
A        20             30
B        5              15
C        40             60
```

How can I achieve this in SQL Server 2008?

Thank you.

Comment: You can achieve this through `PIVOT` or using `CROSS TAB`. Search for `PIVOT` in google you will get thousands of answer

Comment: For reference check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server and http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn on [Pivot](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/)

```
select * from piv
pivot
(
min(oValue)
for oDate in([2014-01-01],[2014-01-02])
)as pivv;
```

Using `Dynamic sql`

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @cols nvarchar(max)

select @cols=stuff((select distinct ','+QUOTENAME(oDate) from piv for xml path(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')

select @query='select * from piv
pivot
(
min(oValue)
for oDate in(' + @cols + ')
)as pivv;'

exec (@query)
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5263c/1)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**dynamic crosstab**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/):

```
DECLARE 
    @sql1   VARCHAR(4000) = '',
    @sql2   VARCHAR(4000) = '',
    @sql3   VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 = 
'SELECT
    oGroup' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   ,MAX(CASE WHEN oDate = CAST(''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), oDate, 112) + ''' AS DATE) THEN oValue END) AS [' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), oDate, 120) +']' + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT oDate FROM SampleData
)t
ORDER BY oDate

SELECT @sql3 = 
'FROM SampleData
GROUP BY oGroup
ORDER BY oGroup'

PRINT(@sql1 + @sql2 +@sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 +@sql3)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a51f5/1/0)

---

This is what the `PRINT` outputs:

```
SELECT
    oGroup
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN oDate = CAST('20140101' AS DATE) THEN oValue END) AS [2014-01-01]
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN oDate = CAST('20140102' AS DATE) THEN oValue END) AS [2014-01-02]
FROM SampleData
GROUP BY oGroup
ORDER BY oGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I am not sure ,I havn't try this

```
SELECT a.ogroup,
       a.ovalue AS '2014-01-01',
       b.ovalue AS '2014-01-02'
FROM   (SELECT *
        FROM   table
        WHERE  odate = '2014-01-01') AS a
       JOIN (SELECT *
             FROM   table
             WHERE  odate = '2014-01-02') AS b
         ON b.ogroup = a.ogroup
```